# PHP failure: imagejpeg and imagecreatefromjpeg

Tags: php, imagejpeg

I check StackOverflow to see if this question has been answered, but didn't find anything corresponding to this.

Running Wampserver 3/Apache 2.4.18/PHP 7.0.4/MySQL 5.7.11. This simple example that I copied from StackOverflow doesn't work -- no image is displayed. Extension php_gd2 is enabled (get_extension_funcs("gd") shows the list).

I had to comment out the `header();` code (even if I put it at line 2), because Firefox complained the code is incorrect with it.

```
<?php
// Create a blank image and add some text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);

// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
//header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Output the image
imagejpeg($im);

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

If I try to load in image from a file:

```
<?php
$thumb = imagecreatefromjpeg("http://localhost/newthumb.jpg");
if( imagejpeg($thumb)){
    imagedestroy($thumb);
    echo "<br>Image2 created";
}
else {
    echo "<br>Image2 not created";
}
?>
```

I get what is tantamount to a character dump of the file (the # are black diamonds with ? in them):

```
####JFIF##>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0  ... 
Image2 created
```

What the !@#$! happened with the new Wampserver/Apache/PHP/MySQL??? What does it take to get images to display in PHP?

Comment: You shouldn't output anything with the image. You _need_ the header to specify the mime type to the browser or else it just interprets it as plain text.

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php where they don't use `header`. Further, from that same page, example 1 works (if I add the header), but example 2 (saving to a file) fails with the "contains errors" message

Apparently it does not like any of (a) mixing text and graphics, which _used_ to work; (b) displaying more than one graphic; or (c) imagejpeg() saving to a file.

Comment: As stated by @Sherif, you need to remove every echo statement and add header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); before imagejpeg($thumb);